# how to find their local transformation by global transformation of 2 points?

Tags: matrix, eigen

In the three-dimensional coordinate system, I know that the transformation from the origin to point A is TransformA, and the transformation from origin to point B is TransformB. I need to find the local conversion matrix from A to B.

I know the following conversion formula

```
// TransformA = Vector3f a, TransformB = Vector3f b
Vector3f a, b;
Vector3f local;
a * local = b
```

Then I use below method to get `local`, but I'm not sure it's right.

```
local = a.inverse() * b;
```

Comment: `a * local = b` does not make any sense. And a `Vector3f` cannot represent a Transformation (other than a translation). Please provide a [mre] of what you are currently doing and describe what you want to do.

Comment: I want to find the conversion matrix from point A to point B